# How to set a batch delete on creation of new document (using triggers)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making a url shortner project (new to firebase), using firestore with collection ref `url/{newDocs}`
for every new document schema as follows:

```
let schema = {
  code: codeGeneratedbyShortidPackage,
  url: req.body.URL,
  expiredAt: Date.now()+60000  // in milisceonds i.e 10 mins for 600000
}
```

---

My question is how to set a batch delete for every document that has exceeded its time limit present inside every doc on addition of a new document at above reference in firestore.

I tried the following code but it didn't worked.

---

```js
exports.deleteFunc = functions.firestore.document('url/{docId}').onCreate( ( change, context) => {
   
   let newbatch = db.batch() ;
   db.collection('nonauth_url').where( 'expiredAt' , '<=', Date.now()).get().then( (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach( (doc) => {
     newbatch.delete(doc.ref) ;
  }) ;
   }).then( () => {
  console.log('Delete done') ;
   }) ;
   return newbatch.commit().then( () => {
  console.log('Batch Committed');
   }).catch( (err) => {
  console.error('error occurred', err) ;
   }) ;
}) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
exports.deleteFunc = functions.firestore
  .document('url/{docId}')
  .onCreate((change, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    let newbatch = db.batch();

    return db
      .collection('nonauth_url')
      .where('expiredAt', '<=', Date.now())
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          newbatch.delete(doc.ref);
        });

        return newbatch.commit();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('error occurred', err);
      });
  });
```

Note that you MUST return a Promise or a value in a background triggered Cloud Function. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ which explain this key point.

Comment: I tried the above code snippet but it didn't worked. Whenever I add any document it does not remove the older docs even after waiting for 10-20 secs docs still persist. Also in cmd when used `firebase serve --only hosting,firestore,functions` sometimes it says Unhandled promise rejection warning but running it again, warning disappears.

Comment: I thoroughly tested the code of my answer, so it shoudl work. When you say "Whenever I add any document it does not remove the older docs", in which Firestore collection do you add a document (any document)?

Comment: What happens if you only keep the `deleteFunc` in the Cloud Function code (`index.js`)?

Comment: On deployment of the project `deleteFunc` is now working perfectly

Comment: "On deployment of the project deleteFunc is now working perfectly" What does it mean exactly? Do you have an error?

Comment: On checking logs in cloud function , logs section `deleteFunc execution started` on every addition of document in that collection which was not logging when running at localhost:5000

Answer (score 1):

Javascript version of the cloud function provided by @renaud-tarnec
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56735180/9646878

For Typescript variant of the above answer

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { HttpsError } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/https';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const onDelete = functions.firestore.document('url/{documentId}')
    .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {

        const docId = context.params.documentId;

        const db = await admin.firestore();
        const newbatch = db.batch();

        try {
            const someHistory = await db.collection('nonauth_url')
                                     .where('expiredAt', '<=', Date.now())
                                     .get();
            someHistory.forEach(history => {
                newbatch.delete(history.ref);
            });
            return newbatch.commit();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('error occurred', err);
            throw new HttpsError('internal', 'Internal Server Error');
        }
    });
```